# Avoid sending meeting invite as attachment when auto-forwarding in Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, gmail, google-calendar-api, outlook-2007

I setup a rule in Outlook 2007 (my work email client) to auto-forward all meeting invites to my Gmail account so I can add them to Google Calendar. I made sure the action I selected was "forward it to people or distribution list" instead of "forward it to people or distribution list as attachment". Despite this, when I look at the forwarded email in Gmail, it just has an attachment with no extension with the name of the meeting. On the other hand, if I forward the invite manually, it is correctly recognized by Gmail as an email invitation. Anything that I might be missing?

Comment: Ask non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Comment: Indeed, it slipped my mind, thanks for reminding me :) In the meantime I'll try your suggestion, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the rule to run a VBA script instead. In that case you will be able to forward the meeting request item programmatically. For example, the code should look like:

```
Public Sub Test(item as MeetingItem)
   ' do whatever you need
End Sub
```

You can call the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869092(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MeetingItem class to execute the Forward action for an item. It returns the resulting copy as a MeetingItem object.